# How to create a circular central menu on Android app

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I need to create something like this in Android:

[image]

It is an app where there is a circular centered menu, the boxes inside are just buttons.

**What kind of frame, widget or component should I use to create this circular shaped menu that is always aligned to the center of the screen on Android?**

Comment: Is the frame your concern or the transparent background?

Comment: @VibhorChopra the main concern is the shape of the menu, it is circular. I will remove the "transparency" from the question.

Comment: google search for `radial menu android` there are many 3rd party libraries, you should use frame layout and add the mapview and menu in it.

Comment: @adelriosantiago : You can use [Android-CircleMenu](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu) for testing case . You need to customize that .